# Grafo de flujo para un algoritmo de división

Tags: ingenieria-del-software, diagrama-de-flujo

Tengo que representar un grafo de flujo del siguiente código que calcula una división (he identificado las diferentes partes del código con las secciones del grafo de abajo):

```
public float calcularDivision(float dividendo, float divisor) throws Exception {
  if (divisor == 0) { // Nodo 1
    throw (new Exception("Error. El divisor no puede ser 0.")); // Nodo 2
  }
  float resultado = dividendo / divisor; // Nodo 3
  return resultado; // Nodo 4
}
```

Esto es lo que he realizado, pero no sé si lo tengo hecho correctamente:

[image: grafo]

Comment: Yo, los diagramas de flujo los dibujo de otra manera. Parece un diagrama de estados. Saludos.

Comment: Puedes mostrarme como lo harías tu?. Saludos.

Comment: Círculos para inicio y fin, cuadraditos para los bloques de acciones, rombos para las condicionales,... al menos así es como yo aprendí los diagramas de flujo. Como dice David, esto parece un diagrama de estados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te ponemos en los comentarios, el gráfico que compartes es más un [diagrama de estados](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_de_transici%C3%B3n_de_estados) que un [diagrama de flujo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_flujo).

De todos modos, el diagrama que compartes parece tener un problema, porque se está pasando del inicio al nodo 1 o al 3, lo cual no sería el caso en tu código. El 1 es un condicional desde el que se puede pasar al estado 2 (si se entra en el `if`) o al 3 (si no se entra). Con ese cambio, el grafo se vería así:

[image: diagrama de estados]

---

Ahora, yo haría el diagrama de flujo de otra manera (con círculos para inicio y fin, cuadraditos para los bloques de acciones, rombos para las condicionales, como se explica en el enlace de arriba):

[image: diagrama de flujo]

donde `divisor = 0?` es el nodo 1, `lanzar excepción` sería el 2, y `realizar operaciones` sería una combinación de los nodos 3 y 4.